# How to log information while starting or stopping services

Tags: logging, service, vbscript

I need to start or stop a service silently but I am not able to log the information correctly.

Below is the code in VBScript written by me.

```js
Dim oFso,oShell,iRet,sLine,sLogName,sLogDir,sDesc,sMasterLog,oMasterLog

Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

StartService "ServiceName"

Sub CheckReturn(iRet)
 If iRet = 0 Then
  Log "Operation completed successfully."
 Else
  Dim sDesc :: sDesc = Err.Description
  Log "Operation failed. Return Code: " & iRet & " Description: " & sDesc
 End If
End Sub

Sub StartService(sName)
 Log "Starting task " & sName
 If (InStr(sName, " ") <> 0) AND (Left(sName, 1) <> chr(34)) Then sName = Chr(34) & sName & Chr(34)
 iRet = oShell.Run("cmd.exe /c net start " & sName, 0, True)
 CheckReturn iRet
End Sub

Sub Log(sLine)
 On Error Resume Next
 If Session.Property("ProductCode") = "" Then
  sLogDir = "" & sLogDir
  sLogName = "" & sLogName
  If sLogDir = "" Then sLogDir = oFso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
  If Not oFso.FolderExists(sLogDir) Then
   oShell.Run "cmd.exe /c MD """ & sLogDir & """", 0, True
   If Not oFso.FolderExists(sLogDir) Then
    sLogDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
   End If
  End If
  If sLogName = "" Then sLogName = Left(WScript.ScriptName, Len(WScript.ScriptName) - 4) & "_Master_" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Now, " ", "_"), ":", "."), "/", ".") & ".log"
  sMasterLog = sLogDir & "\" & sLogName
  Set oMasterLog = oFso.OpenTextFile(sMasterLog, 8, True)
  Err.Clear
  oMasterLog.WriteLine Now & " : " & sLine
  oMasterLog.Close
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then WScript.Quit
  oMasterLog.Close
  Set oMasterLog = Nothing
 Else
  Dim oRec
  Set oRec = Session.Installer.CreateRecord(1)
  oRec.StringData(1) = Now & " : " & sLine
  Session.Message &H04000000, oRec
 End If
End Sub
```

When I am trying to start a service like Fax, it will fail in my machine but it is not logging the information correctly.

When I tried to run in command prompt.I am getting information as

**> The Fax service is starting. The Fax service could not be started.

> The service did not report an error.
>
> More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.**

But when I am checking the error code in VBS or in commnd prompt by seeing the value of %errorlevel%, it is giving 2 instead of 3534.

Please help me on this how to write to log file correctly for starting or stopping a service.

Answer (score 0):

Run return %ERRORLEVEL%.

*"The principal difference between Exec and Run is that Exec supports real-time output to the user (if it is a command-line program), but we can't get ERRORLEVEL using this method."*

> it is giving 2 instead of 3534.

2 is %ERRORLEVEL%

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156605.aspx